# Origin not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: javascript, polyfills

I'll caveat this with the fact that I am not a Javascript expert. Not even close.

That said, I'm using a [Javascript Polyfill](https://github.com/chuckcarpenter/REM-unit-polyfill/) to allow me to use rem units for text size on a web page and maintain IE8 compatibility:

http://www.joannecorryhair.co.uk/

The script is referenced on line 24:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="scripts/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/0.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/600.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/740.css" />
    <script src="scripts/rem.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

In IE8 only (even if I put this outside of the conditional meta tags), the console throws the following error and this script doesn't work (font spacing is all messed up):

> Origin http://joannecorryhair.co.uk not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

This works perfectly locally.

I suspect this is something on the server config, as this is a very popular polyfill. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, the problem is a clash with Google Fonts. You need to add 'data-norem' toyour Google Font tag like this example: <link data-norem href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300|Roboto+Condensed:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Answer (score 0):

This error shows up because you are attempting to load assets (images, audio or video) or data (JSON or XML) across domains. The site that is serving the data/assets needs to allow your site to use those assets by setting a CORS header.

More Info: http://www.enable-cors.org

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed the CORS header as suggested in Patrick's answer, however, I'll post the details separately so they're easier for users to find.

The issue is that I am using Google Webfonts. It is Google whose CORS header is incompatible. You need to add the following to your Google Font CSS reference:

```
data-norem
```

So it will look like this:

```
<link data-norem href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I found this info in the Rem Polyfill issues register here:

https://github.com/chuckcarpenter/REM-unit-polyfill/issues/51